# Cuál es la real diferencia entre los operadores en PHP?

Tags: php

*Creo que el false funciona como 0 y el 1 como true, tal como en `Javascript`*

*Pero, si el operador `+` es para sumar números*
*y el operador `.` es para sumar cadenas, por qué aca me suma **como** números?*

```
echo true . false;
```

***Si me dijeran que AUTOMÁTICAMENTE, los transforma a números porqué no sucede lo mismo en este ejemplo:***

```
echo 4 . 6;
```

Answer (score 6):

Te estás equivocando:

> (string)true; ==> "1"
>   (string)false; ==> ""
>   true . false; ==> "1"
>
> (string)4; ==> "4"
>   (string)6; ==> "6"
>   4 . 6; ==> "46"

Comment: Entonces no hay manera de imprimir true y false("truelfalse") como CADENA, sin tener que escribirlo textualmente

Comment: Va ser que no. Tienes que comprobarlo antes, con un `if( )`, un ternario `?:`, o , en PHP7, usando `??`. Pero directamente, me parece que no :-(

Comment: Ah vale, como en javascript si se puede ando algo acostumbrado, gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Porque cuando haces esto :

```
echo 4 . 6;
```

En realidad estas concatenando los valores no sumandolo. Es facil probarlo, solo agrega mas valores a la concatenacion y veras como lo muestra todo junto:

```
echo 4 . 6 . 9 . 6;
```

Php es un lenguaje debilmente tipado por lo que el mismo hace la conversion de `int` a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesante pregunta.

Si usas `var_dump` podrás saber lo que ocurre.

Generalmente, aunque no siempre, ocurre lo que se ha comentado en otras respuestas: PHP hace la conversión de tipos asignando los valores respectivos. En el caso de `false` es una cadena vacía `""`, y en el caso de `true` es `1`.

**Pero** si interviene un operador, PHP crea un valor del tipo `int` como veremos en el código más abajo.

Si quieres imprimir directamente `true` o `false` puedes valerte de `var_export` para  ello. Por ejemplo esto:

```
echo var_export(true,true)
```

Imprimirá:

```
true
```

Y esto:

```
echo var_export(false,true)
```

Imprimirá:

```
false
```

Veamos todo la afirmado expresado en fragmentos de código:

#### Código

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/LCCFR90755)**</kbd>

```
<?php 
echo "Crea una cadena que combina cadena en blanco y 1:\n";
var_dump (true . false);

echo "\nCrea una cadena que combina dos cadenas en blanco:\n";
var_dump (false . false);


echo "\nCrea una cadena que combina dos valores 1:\n";
var_dump (true . true);

echo "\nCrea un entero que suma 1 + 1:\n";
var_dump (true + true);

echo "\nCrea un entero que suma 1 + 0:\n";
var_dump (true + false);

echo "\nCrea un entero que resta 1 + 1:\n";
var_dump (true - true);

echo "\nvar_dump (true / false); daría  Warging Division by zero\n";
// var_dump (true / false); //Daría Warning Division by zero

echo "\nCrea una cadena combinando 4 y 6:\n";
var_dump (4 . 6);

echo "\nAl intervenir un operador matemático crea un entero:\n";
var_dump (4 . 6 + 1);

/* Imprimiendo como true o false con var_export*/

echo "\nvar_export() para false:\n";
$bolFalse = false;
echo var_export($bolFalse, true)."\n";

echo "\nvar_export() para true:\n";
$bolTrue = true;
echo var_export($bolTrue, true)."\n";

echo "\nvar_export() combinado imposible:\n";
$strTrueFalse = true . false;
echo var_export($strTrueFalse, true);

?>
```

#### Resultado:

```
Crea una cadena que combina cadena en blanco y 1:
string(1) "1"

Crea una cadena que combina dos cadenas en blanco:
string(0) ""

Crea una cadena que combina dos valores 1:
string(2) "11"

Crea un entero que suma 1 + 1:
int(2)

Crea un entero que suma 1 + 0:
int(1)

Crea un entero que resta 1 + 1:
int(0)

var_dump (true / false); daría  Warning Division by zero

Crea una cadena combinando 4 y 6:
string(2) "46"

Al intervenir un operador matemático crea un entero:
int(47)

var_export() para false:
false

var_export() para true:
true

var_export() combinado imposible:
'1'
```

Comment: Le felicito estimado, sus respuestas siempre son bastante completas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ArieCwHat